# finalize() method not getting called despite WeakReference

Tags: java

I am currently having an issue with objects of a class of mine not having their `finalize()` method called, despite only being stored in a `ConcurrentHashMap` as values, and the Object's `UUID` as the keys for the map.

Here is an example I have created (it isn't the one used in my actual project but this example also does not have the objects' `finalize()` methods called.

TestMain.class //The main class handling the HashMap

```
public class TestMain {

public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, WeakReference<Test>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, WeakReference<Test>>();

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    map.put("Key1", new WeakReference<Test>(new Test("test 1", 2))); //This "Test" Object shouldn't be accessible anywhere besides the HashMap anymore, and therefore I want it to be "finalized" by the garbage collector.
    System.out.println("DONE");
  } 
}
```

Test.class //The Object Class

```
public class Test {
  public String string;

  public int intt;

  public Test(String string, int intt) {
    this.string = string;
    this.intt = intt;
  }

  @Override
  protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("FINALIZED TEST CLASS: " + string);
    super.finalize();
  }
}
```

When the main method is run, all that is printed is "DONE" when I expected "FINALIZED TEST CLASS: Test 1" to also be printed prior to that. Is there something wrong with my code, or am I misunderstanding how `finalize()` works?

Also, I wish for this to work as I explain because I need the objects with the `finalize()` methods to be erased from the "map" `Map` and from memory as there will be several hundred of the object generated during my project's run duration, so I want the objects no longer in use to be cleared to make room for more new ones.

EDIT: I have seen elsewhere on the internet that people say the program might terminate before the garbage collector has a chance to dispose of the said objects. Therefore, I have attempted to let my program not terminate by adding a simple `while(true){}` loop and waited for a couple of minutes, and still did not see the message of the object being "finalized".

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: There is no guarantee of finalize method will be called

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera So how would I manually dispose of these objects after they are no longer accessible anywhere else? I am decently confused right now

Comment: @C_Beth it's not your job, GC will take care of that. When you try to do it yourself it will cause extra headaches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rightly mentioned in comments, there is no guarantee of finalize method being called.

> The Java programming language does not guarantee which thread will
>   invoke the finalize method for any given object. It is guaranteed,
>   however, that the thread that invokes finalize will not be holding any
>   user-visible synchronization locks when finalize is invoked. If an
>   uncaught exception is thrown by the finalize method, the exception is
>   ignored and finalization of that object terminates.

Now coming back to your concern of manually disposing these objects after they are no longer accessible, you need not handle that, Java Garbage collector would handle that for you with it's automatic memory management. If you want to accelerate garbage collection, read on G1 Garbage collector.

Comment: Alright thanks; I didn't know the GC would automatically run only if it needs to.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely explanation is that the GC never ran.

- If the GC doesn't run, then objects won't be garbage collected.
- If objects are not collected, they won't be finalized.

> have attempted to let my program not terminate by adding a simple while(true){} loop and waited for a couple of minutes,

Waiting for the GC is not going to help.  Normally it only runs when it >>needs to<< run; i.e. when one of the heap spaces exceeds a threshold of fullness.

You can force the GC to run by calling `System.gc()` ... but that is **BAD PRACTICE**.  It will make your application inefficient and non-responsive.

It is also unwise to try to try to do anything in finalizers that has to be done in a timely fashion.  You should design your code so that:

- it doesn't matter if an object never gets finalized at all, and
- it doesn't matter when an object gets finalized.

Why?  Because you have little control over when objects get finalized ... and none at all if you don't call `System.gc()` ... which you should not do; see above.

In practice, finalizers are a feature of Java that should be used rarely, if at all.  The only valid use-cases involve releasing external resources associated with resource objects that the application has not tidied up.  Even then, it is better for the application to use "try with resources" (or a `finally` block) to clean up the resources explicitly.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/a8w7rq Added the `System.gc()` and it did prove that when the GC is called it will all work correctly. Thank you